# How force gcc to use two different registers to operands in asm?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 compiled for sam7s processor.

I need to use some inline assembly:

```
int res;
asm volatile (" \
        MRS r0,CPSR     \n  \
        MOV %0, r0      \n  \
        BIC r0,r0,%1    \n  \
        MSR CPSR,r0     \n  \
        " : "=r" (res) : "r" (0xc0) : "r0" );
return res;
```

Which is translated by gcc to (comments added by me):

```
mov r3, #192    ; load 0xc0 to r3
str r0, [sl, #56]   ; preserve value of r0?

mrs r0, CPSR    ; load CPSR to r0
mov r3, r0      ; save r0 to "res"; r3 overwritten!
bic r0, r0, r3  ; 
msr CPSR_fc, r0 ;
```

The problem is that in place of "%0" (res) and "%1" (constant: 0xc0) the same register "r3" is used. For this reason %1 is overwritten before it is used, and code work incorrectly.

The question is how can I forbid gcc to use the same register for input/output operands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally i've found it [here](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/a-brief-tutorial-on-gcc-inline-asm)

> & says that an output operand is written to before the inputs are
>   read, so this output must not be the same register as any input.
>   Without this, gcc may place an output and an input in the same
>   register   even if not required by a "0" constraint.  This is very
>   useful, but   is mentioned here because it's specific to an
>   alternative.  Unlike   = and %, but like ?, you have to include it
>   with each alternative to   which it applies.

After changing `"=r" (res)` to `"=&r" (res)` everything works fine.